# Replacing line in text file with python. How to?

Tags: python

I've looking for here and there how to replace multiple lines in file with new ones but my code just add a line to very end of file. How to replace old line with new one in proper place ?

```
path = /path/to/file
new_line = ''
f = open(path,'r+b')
f_content = f.readlines()
line = f_content[63]
newline = line.replace(line, new_line)
f.write(newline)
f.close()
```

edited:
    path = /path/to/file
    path_new = path+".tmp"
    new_line = ""
    with open(path,'r') as inf, open(path_new, 'w') as outf:
        for num, line in enumerate(inf):
            if num == 64:
                newline = line.replace(line, new_line)
                outf.write(newline)
            else:
                outf.write(line)
    new_file = os.rename(path_new, path)

Comment: try using `f_content.seek(n)` , where n is the index of line .  `seek(0)` takes to start of file.

Comment: Is the new line the same length as the old?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you have to rewrite the whole file.

The operating system exposes a file as a sequence of bytes. This sequence has a so-called *file pointer* associated with it when you open the file. When you open the file, the pointer is at the beginning. You can read or write bytes from this location, but you *cannot* insert or delete bytes. After reading or writing *n* bytes, the file pointer will have shifted *n* bytes.

Additionally Python has a method to read the whole file and split the contents into a list of lines. In this case this is more convenient.

```
# Read everything
with open('/path/to/file') as infile:
    data = infile.readlines()
# Replace
try:
    data[63] = 'this is the new text\n' # Do not forget the '\n'!
    with open('/path/to/file', 'w') as newfile:
        newfile.writelines(data)
except IndexError:
    print "Oops, there is no line 63!"
```

Comment: thank you so mach,Roland, it works at last! One more a little question: what syntax should be to replace  'this is the new text' with variable?

Comment: @AndriyKravchenko Just use `data[63] = variable`

Answer (score 2):

Most operating systems treat files as binary stream, so there is nothing like a line in a file. Therefore you have to rewrite the whole file, with the line substituted:

```
new_line = ''
with open(path,'r') as inf, open(path_new, 'w') as outf:
    for num, line in enumerate(inf):
        if num == 64:
           outf.write(new_line)
        else:
           outf.write(line)
os.rename(path_new, path)
```

Comment: if path_new and path are the same code just creates empty file

Comment: correct, because it is overwritten! You need a temporary second filename, say `path_new = path + ".tmp"`.